# Proof of a equality-topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider he topological space $ (X,\tau)$ and $A \subseteq X$.
I want to prove that these are equivalent:

(i)$A\in \tau$ ($A$ is open)~

(ii) For any $B\subseteq X$, where $A\cap B=\emptyset$  then, $A\cap \overline B =\emptyset$

I have started in this way:

(i) $\to$ (ii)

$B\subseteq X$, where $A\cap B=\emptyset$ if and only if (As $A$ is open) $A^\circ\cap B = \emptyset $ if and only if $A^\circ\cap (B^\circ)^\circ = \emptyset$ if and only if $(A\cap B^\circ)^\circ = \emptyset$ if and only if $X-(A\cap B^\circ)^\circ =X$  if and only if $\overline{X-(A\cap B^\circ)} =X$.....

But I don't get to any point

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is open, then $X -A $ is closed.  If $A \cap B = \varnothing$, then $B \subset X-A$.  Then $\overline{B} \subset \overline{X-A} = X-A$, so $A \cap \overline{B} = \varnothing$.

Conversely, if all sets $B$ disjoint from $A$ are such that $A \cap \overline{B} = \varnothing$.  Then $A \cap \overline{X-A} = \varnothing \implies \overline{X-A} \subset X-A$, or $X-A$ is closed, so $A$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for (i)$\implies$(ii): If $A$ is open and $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then $B$ is a subset of the closed set $X-A$.

For the other direction, take $B=X-A$